Show that $\sum_{n \leq x} \left( \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \right)^\kappa = c(\kappa)x + O(x^\epsilon)$.

Let $\kappa$ be a fixed real number. Show that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \left( \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \right)^\kappa = c(\kappa)x + O(x^\epsilon),$$
where
$$c(\kappa) = \prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \left( 1 - (1-1/p)^\kappa \right) \right).$$

I've been working on this problem for a while without making any progress. The main challenge lies in the $\kappa$ exponent, which complicates associating a Dirichlet convolution to $(\phi(n)/n)^{\kappa}$. This makes the standard methods ineffective. Summation by parts might be a viable approach, but I can't see a clear path forward. I suspect it would require analyzing $\phi(n)^{\kappa}$, and I don't have a good handle on that either. Any suggestions?

What is the Dirichlet series associated to $(\phi(n)/n)^k$?

@Conrad $\sum_{n} \phi(n)^{\kappa} n^{-s-\kappa}$?

What about you write it in terms of a product on primes? Note that for any prime power $\phi(p^m)/p^m=1-1/p$ doesn't depend on $m$ so the product has terms $1+(1-1/p)^kp^{-s}/(1-p^{-s})$

So in particular if $h=\muf$ you have $h(p)=(1-1/p)^{\kappa}-1, h(p^m)=0, m \ge 2$ while $f=h1$ so you can conclude by standard techniques

What's the context of this problem?

@Conrad Thank you, I'll think about your approach. Might post as an answer later if I solve it.

@GregMartin This is an exercise in Montgomery and Vaughan's MNT book.

if you have any difficulty proceeding I could write a solution but it is really a standard exercise once you get the trick of writing $f=h*1$ for your $f(n)=(\phi(n)/n)^{\kappa}$ as above

@Conrad I believe I’ve solved it below, though I’m slightly uneasy about some of the bounds I used for $h$. We seem to obtain a better error term, $O(\log x)$.

EDIT: My original proof contained a mistake where I failed to account for certain contributions from the Taylor expansion terms of $(1 - x)^{\kappa} - 1$ around $x = 0$. This also explains why the original appeared to yield a better error term, namely $O(\log x)$, which was incorrect. It should be fixed now.
PROOF: Following Conrad's hint, we observe that for $s$ with sufficiently large real part,
$$
\sum_{n} \phi^{\kappa}(n) n^{-s-\kappa} = \prod_{p}\left(1+\sum_{m} p^{(m-1)\kappa}(p-1)^{\kappa} p^{-m(s+\kappa)}\right) \\ 
= \prod_p \frac{-p^{-s} + 1 + (1-1/p)^{\kappa} p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}} = \zeta(s)\prod_p \left(1 + \left((1-1/p)^{\kappa} - 1\right)p^{-s}\right).
$$
From this, we can write $\phi^{\kappa}(n)n^{-\kappa} = \sum_{d \mid n} h(d)$, where $h$ is the multiplicative function such that $h(p) = (1-1/p)^{\kappa}-1$ for primes $p$ and $h(p^m) = 0$ for $m > 1$. Then, using standard techniques, we have
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \phi^{\kappa}(n) n^{-\kappa} = x \sum_{d \leq x} \frac{h(d)}{d} + O\left(\sum_{d \leq x} |h(d)|\right).
$$
To conclude the proof, we require a few key estimates. First,
$$
\sum_{d \leq x} \frac{h(d)}{d} = \sum_{\substack{d \leq x \\ d \text{ square-free}}} \frac{1}{d} \prod_{p \mid d} \left((1 - 1/p)^{\kappa} - 1\right) \leq \sum_{d \leq x} \frac{(M|\kappa|)^{\omega(d)}}{d^2},$$
for some $M > 0$, $\kappa \neq 0$ (the case $\kappa = 0$ is obvious). This inequality follows from the first-order Taylor expansion of $(1 - x)^{\kappa} - 1$ around $x = 0$. Next, there exists a constant $A > 0$ such that $\omega(d) \leq A \log d / \log \log d$ for all $d \geq 3$. Then, for $M |\kappa| \geq 1$, we have
$$
(M |\kappa|)^{\omega(d)} \leq (M |\kappa|)^{A \log d / \log \log d} = d^{A \log (M |\kappa|) / \log \log d},
$$
and, for $M |\kappa| < 1$, we can apply the trivial inequality $(M |\kappa|)^{\omega(d)} \leq 1$. Now, fix an arbitrary $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. The above bounds imply that $(M |\kappa|)^{\omega(d)} \ll d^{\varepsilon}$, where the implicit constant is adjusted to hold for all $d \geq 1$. Combining this with the initial inequality gives
$$
\sum_{d \leq x} \frac{h(d)}{d} \ll \sum_{d \leq x} \frac{1}{d^{2 - \varepsilon}} \ll 1,
$$
where the latter sum is $O(1)$ because $2 - \varepsilon > 1$. Similarly, $\sum_{d > x} h(d)/d \ll x^{-(1-\varepsilon)}$. Note also that $\sum_{d} h(d)/d$ is absolutely convergent. Hence, using Euler products, we have
$$
\sum_{d} \frac{h(d)}{d} = \prod_p \left(1 + \left((1-1/p)^{\kappa} - 1\right)p^{-1}\right),
$$
which is the constant $c(\kappa)$ from the statement. Finally, by an entirely analogous argument, we obtain $\sum_{d \leq x} |h(d)| \ll x^{\varepsilon}$. This completes the proof.

Looks right to me -
